# How to call external scripts and img links in master page of "asp.net empty web site" in VS2019

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, image

I want to call external `scripts` and `img links` in `HomeMaster page` and also I have created a `Home.aspx` page under the `homepage` folder and I have created this project using `asp.net empty web site` in VS2019. So while I'm running the `Home.aspx` page the page is executing but the related `css`,`js`,`img` links are not loading properly.

This is my project structure :-

[image: project structure]

And I'm calling the `scripts`, `img` links in HomeMaster page like this.

In header

```
<head runat="server">

   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Path</title>
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="../assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="../assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="../assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Main CSS File -->
  <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And in body after footer content(at the end) calling the js related files :-

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="../assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Main JS File -->
  <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And in `Home.aspx` page  calling the `img` links like below :-

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HomeMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="homepage_Home" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

  <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src="../assets/img/clients/client-1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src="../assets/img/clients/client-2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src="../assets/img/clients/client-3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src="../assets/img/clients/client-4.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src="../assets/img/clients/client-5.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src="../assets/img/clients/client-6.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>

        </div>

</asp:Content>
```

So while I'm running the `Home.aspx` page I didn't get any error and the images are not displaying in `Home.aspx` page

I'm very new to this `web site forms` development.

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your master page?

The master page is in your root, so no need to "cork" down one folder as you have

eg this:

```
<script src="../assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
```

That should be this

```
<script src="/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
```

(Assuming above is in your master page).

You can always test/check by opening the master page, and then from one of those folders, simple drag in the js file into the master page.

So, say like this:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script src="/Scripts/Test.js"></script>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
                    <h3>My Master page part</h3>
        <br />

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the path name is from your "master" page

So, the above js script file is this:

```
function myhello() {

    alert("Hello")

}
```

So, now say if I add a web page (with master) say in this folder:

[image]

So, ok, that new web page (with master) is nested, but I can still in code use that js function myhello()

eg:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button"
            OnClientClick="myhello();return false" />

</asp:Content>
```

So, your script references need to be starting from root (same as master page).

The above (or any page) can now freely use that myhello() function I included in the master page - and nesting will not matter.

Of course if you want ONLY some pages in a given web page (master, or not with master), then relative path names WILL be required.